# Docker Hub - Automatic build on tag with regex match not triggered

Tags: git, docker, dockerhub

I am setting up a repository to automate the deployment of a web-app.

To manage the master branch releases i use tags in git to mark every release ex: `0.0.4`, `0.0.5` and so on..

I notices that docker hub recently updated their Auto-build system and introduced a regex match. What i am trying to do is to get a image built every time i push a new tag to the branch.

My issue is that when i set up a new auto build on tag and regex like 
`/^[0-9.]+$/` it doesn't get triggered to build? It works fine if i just set up a auto build on branch with the latest tag, then every time i push anything to the branch i get a new latest build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a response for docker hub support that solved my issue:

> All newly created automated build repos referencing BitBucket source
>   will be able to have dynamic build triggers based on Git tags.
>
> However, for existing automated build repos, created before 29th
>   December 2015, there is a catch. In order for these existing repos to
>   have tag-based dynamic build triggers, you would need to do either of
>   the following:
>
> The painful way: You will need to remove/delete your automated build
>   repo on Docker Hub and set it up again.
>
> The less painful way: Go to your BitBucket repo settings page
>   (https://bitbucket.org///admin), click on the
>   Services tab under Integration. You should see Docker Hub as one of
>   services listed, likely with an entry that looks like this: POST
>   https://registry.hub.docker.com/hooks/bitbucket. Copy the URL
>   (https://registry.hub.docker.com/hooks/bitbucket) and then click on
>   the Webhooks tab under Integration, then proceed to Add webhook. The
>   title should be "Docker Hub", paste the copied URL in the URL field,
>   tick the "Active" box, and select the "Repository push" option for
>   Triggers. The final configuration should look like the attached
>   screenshot. Last but not least, save the configuration. If you have
>   done either of the above steps, your automated build repo on Docker
>   Hub would trigger new builds when you push any tags to your BitBucket
>   repo.

Answer (score 1):

For GitHub I had to do the following

- Log into hub.docker.com and navigate to the appropriate repo eg [Fluentd - papertrail](https://hub.docker.com/r/timothyclarke/docker-fluentd-es-pt/)

  - Go to **Build Settings** and in the **Build Triggers** section generate a token. You should have something that looks like *https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/timothyclarke/docker-fluentd-es-pt/trigger/<UUID>/* in the Trigger URL box
  - Copy the **Trigger URL**
- Go to GitHub and navigate to the repo you want to build from

  - Go to **Settings** of the repo, then **Webhooks**
  - Click **Add webhook** and paste the **Trigger URL** from docker hub into the *Payload URL* box then click the **Add webhook** at the bottom.
  - Note you probably want to select individual events and limit them to commits, tags etc

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the process of setting up an example repository. For me the automated setup didn't work. What I had to do was to add the Docker service to my repo on GitHub and all my pushes automatagically started triggering builds.